# how to refresh the div block in specific time

Tags: php, jquery

How can I refresh the div block in specific time so that changes made in database can be seen in browser.So that, I don't have hit **F5** every time to see the changes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried loading the whole page using <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.mydomain.com/page.html">

Comment: @AshokMaharjan:you want to refresh the page or only the div block? If you want to refresh only the div block load a url to that div using jquery ajax with setTimeout or setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Delay is the time in milliseconds
var delay = 60000;

var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
    $('#YourDivID').fadeOut("slow").load('Recent_updates.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` javascript methods that allow use to call function after periodic time.

`setInterval(function(){ },2000);` where 2000 is time in millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout(expression, timeout); runs the code/function once after the timeout.

setInterval(expression, timeout); runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them.

Example:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(alert, 1000); // Will alert every second.
// clearInterval(intervalID); // Will clear the timer.

setTimeout(alert, 1000); // Will alert once, after a second.
```

example on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fengelz/Svx3n/

Answer (score 0):

use jquery,  Load the contents of the div block via an ajax call. then use a timer function in javascript to reload the ajax load function every xx seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your div:

```
<div id="divId">...</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $('#divId').load('your_file.html');
}, 1000) // every 1000 milliseconds
```

When you want to stop cycling refresh just call

```
crealInterval(auto_refresh);
```